# How to export a SharePoint 2013 List without content?

Tags: list, custom-form, export, import

**Hi everyone!**
I have a list on my SharePoint site and I want to use the same list on another site. With 'Create a list template' I can just use the list on my subsites.

I don't want the content, just the columns, forms (newform, editform,..) .. yes I guess that's it!

I could use content types, but the forms wouldn't be in it and it would be more effort than to just import the whole list.

Oh, and I've never used PowerShell before, so I hope there is an easier way (through SharePoint etc.?)

**Thanks for your ideas!**

Answer (score 0):

Go to List Settings, Export as Template. There you can decide if you want to save the list content in your template.

Comment: yes, but I want to use the list on another site (no subsite) so I guess a template will not work for me

Comment: You can use the template in other sites, even on other farms.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your list as template from List setting and uncheck the check box for not including the content and after saving you can use the list as template for creating new list.
[For more reference you can refer link](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/10/14/using-list-templates-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: yes, but I want to use the list on another site (no subsite) so I guess a template will not work for me

Comment: just try it will work